# Is it still recommended to only use relative font-size for accessibility?

Tags: fonts, accessibility

I have read in the past that it is recommended to use only relative sized fonts in web pages of accessibility.  Is this still the case?  Using [Bootsrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap) from IE7, for example, which uses `body{ font-size: 14px; }` makes changing the text size do nothing.  Is this how a user with functional needs would use the page, or would the user use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseWheelUp</kbd> method which actually increases the web page size, not just the text.  After doing some searches online, I cannot find any definitive up to date information.

[This issues](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1943) has been raised in the Bootstrap issue tracker, though, but [Mark Otto](https://github.com/mdo) thinks [it is not a concern](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1943#issuecomment-10540576), stating "browsers scale up entire pages these days, so it's not an issue with type scaling or anything."

[image: IE7 Text Size Switching]

Comment: While I have no reference to back this up, I think using relative font-size is an ideal that leads to considerably more headaches than it is worth. Whenever there is graphics or video on the same page, it just does not hold up.

Comment: Using relative font sizes is a good idea, but it requires a design that will accommodate variable fonts. Sadly, not all designers make those.

Comment: There are some CSS frameworks that were built with accessibility in mind, like [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/) (why could they not choose another name?) But yeah, it seems like there are a bunch of issues cajoling Bootstrap into being accessible.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want good accessibility then you should consider IE6 and IE7. Bootstrap has limited support in IE6 and IE7 - Chrome, Firefox, and Safari do not encounter this problem. It is important to note that Twitter Bootstrap is a framework and not everything is done for you out of the box, it can be easily adapted to do what you want it too do with JavaScript.

**Bootstrap and Modernizr**

With using Modernizr you can easily integrate separate rules for ie6 and ie7 by using the css class:

Default font size: `body .ie7 {font-size:100%;}` or `body .ie7 {font-size:large;}`

Additionally you can always use JavaScript to switch font sizes by clicking +/- on the screen: [Demo can be viewed here](http://d.alistapart.com/relafont/example.html) and would use something like this:

- xsmall.css  > `body {font-size:x-small;}`
- small.css   > `body {font-size:small;}`
- large.css   > `body {font-size:large;}`
- xlarge.css  > `body {font-size:x-large;}`
- xxlarge.css > `body {font-size:xx-large;}`

Personally I would go the [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) route and get the CSS working with IE6 and IE7

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use em, % or rem, instead of px.  This site gives a good explanation as to which and where you would use one over the other:

https://medium.com/@madhum86/css-font-sizing-pixels-vs-em-vs-rem-vs-percent-vs-viewport-units-b1485716afe7